# Which sites have the most prominent top users?

Tags: support, reputation, data-explorer, statistics, top-users

I was looking at the [top users of Chess Stack Exchange](https://chess.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) and noticed the top user @BrianTowers has more than twice the reputation (79k) of the next user @PhishMaster (32.1k). Are there more Stack Exchange sites where this happens? What is the site with the greatest difference (both relative and absolute)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) can be used to answer questions like this. [Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1619753/comparison-of-top-users-of-each-site#resultSets) is a SQL query which compares relative differences:

[image]

and clicking on the [1/2] reveals the absolute differences:

[image]

The bottom parts of both lists are also interesting; sites with effectively two or more top users by reputation.

Please note that SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning, and if you want to experiment yourself, feel free to fork these queries or one of the others contributed by the community there.